# What is the probability that an element is in a subset of a set, given a set of subsets.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a set of natural numbers,

$$A = \{1,...,n\}$$

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of $k<n$ elements from a uniform random sample without replacement from $A \setminus \{ \pi \}$, for a $\pi \in A$. From the resulting ordered set
$\mathcal{S} \cup \{\pi \}$, the chance of correctly guessing which elements corresponds to $\pi$ is

$$\frac{1}{k+1}$$

For example, $n=10$, $k=3$ and $\pi=7$, a possible resulting subset is
$$M_7= \{3,5,7,9\}$$
If you do not know $\pi$, there is a $1/4$ chance of correct guessing $\pi=7$. If we build another set for a different $\pi$,

$$M_2= \{2,3,7,9\}$$

would the overall chance of correctly guessing the $\pi$ from each $M_{\pi}$ decrease as more subsets are presented? The overall lower bound of guessing is bounded by $1/n$. Is it possible to achieve this bound as more $M_{\pi}$ are issued?

The subsets $M_{\pi}$ are independent from each other, so first one would have to guess the correct set out of $l$ subsets and then the correct element from $k+1$ elements in the subset.

\begin{equation}
P(\pi = a|M_a) = \frac{1}{k+1} \cdot \frac{1}{l}
\end{equation}

The probability as a function of the number of subsets with $n=3200$ is plotted in the Figure. A large $k$ converges faster to $1/n$ but increases the storage space.

[Convergece plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pZOO.png)

Goal: For each element in $i \in A$, issue a subset $M_i$. Given the ensamble of subsets, the probability of correctly guessing $i$ from $M_i$ grows from $1/|M_i|$ to $1/n$ as more subsets are considered, reducing space. I was wondering if my thoughts and conclusion are correct.

Comment: Intuitively, there are better guessing algorithms than just picking at random since you have a lot of information. For example, consider $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $k=2$, $M_1=\{1,2\}$, $M_2=\{1,2\}$, $M_3=\{2,3\}$. Then, you know that $\pi$ in $M_3$ is $3$ and your overall probability of guessing everything correctly is $1/2$.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right. For that, I was thinking that somehow I need to incorporate the chance that an element is in a combination, which is $k/n$. As in the birthday paradox, there is a difference between correctly guessing a specific $\pi$, and the overall chance of guessing a $\pi$. It would be nice if someone could help me out in the right direction.